# Can't addsubview when call method from appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm calling this method in appdelegate

```
[[[ViewController alloc] init] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

method in ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
-(void)callMethod;
@end
```

method in ViewController.m

```
-(void)callMethod{
    NSLog(@"Method was call.....");
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.113725F green:0.615686F blue:0.411765F alpha:1.0F];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

}
```

it can print in console but addSubView doesn't work.
how to make addSubView work.
Thank. :)

Comment: Put the code you used to show `ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first `push` this new allocated view controller `[[ViewController alloc] init]` on the stack so see it. Or if this controller was already *pushed* or *tabbed*, *you don't have to re-allocate it* using `alloc` keyword.

Try like this in *appdelegate*:

```
// Get the visible viewController
ViewController *vc = [self.navigationController visibleViewController];
[vc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I got this error : 
Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: Your app is navigation based or tabbed based ? Where this view controller resides in window ? I have given you a suggestion, this code may not execute as-it-is. You have to find out where this view controller is in window, if it is visible. perform selector to do an action.